# Any good replacement for HttpPost and HttpPut with some "setEntity" method on android?

Tags: android, http, http-post, http-put

I'm currently using HttpPost and HttpPut to send an entity from my mobile app to the server. I'm using the setEntity to send entities from database to server and it's easy, straight forward and it's working perfectly, but it was now removed from the support library in version 23.
The few things I have found to replace HttpPost and HttpPut don't have any method like setEntity and the refactor would be really complicated. Isn't there such way or I just couldn't find it? Any suggestions?
I tried to add Http back using

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[`httpclient-android`](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android) is a port of apache `HttpClient` for android 23+.  You can in include it with --

```
compile "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1"
```

You will need to change your import statements to have the new package name as well.